# C# intercambiar minúsculas por mayúsculas y viceversa en una palabra

Tags: c#, .net

estaba realizando un ejercicio el cual se me pide que al ingresar una palabra, la salida muestra la misma pero con la diferencia que todas las minúsculas que contenía pasaran a mayúscula y las mayúsculas a minúsculas, logro hacer la conversión pero a la hora de mostrar la misma palabra pero con sus letras cambiadas me marca un error de que no tengo asignada 'salida', mi pregunta es ¿que debería hacer para obtener la palabra cambiada, desde ya muchas gracias.

```
        var line1 = System.Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        char salida;

        foreach (char valor in line1)
        {                
            if (Char.IsLower(valor))
            {
                salida = Char.ToUpper(valor);
            }
            else
            {
                salida = Char.ToLower(valor);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(salida);                
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine(salida);//linea de error
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice [Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20785/7242) el compilador no sabe si la variable `salida` tiene valor o no al salir del `foreach` pero me gustaría añadir que no estás guardando la conversión en ninguna variable y no estás imprimiendo, como has dicho, la palabra al final.

Para hacerlo asignamos una nueva variable `lineaSalida` que contenga las conversiones que vas realizando y al final imprime el resultado:

```
var line1 = System.Console.ReadLine().Trim();
string lineaSalida = string.Empty;
char salida;

foreach (char valor in line1)
{                
    if (Char.IsLower(valor))
    {
        salida = Char.ToUpper(valor);
    }
    else
    {
        salida = Char.ToLower(valor);
    }
    lineaSalida += salida;
    System.Console.WriteLine(salida);                
}
System.Console.WriteLine(lineaSalida);//Muestra la linea como quieres
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 2):

No es un problema con la ejecución, sino con la lógica del **compilador**, que da el siguiente error:

> Use of unassigned local variable `salida'

El compilador no sabe de antemano que dentro del `if` se va a asignar un valor a `salida`, por eso te da ese error. Una forma de hacerselo entender podría ser asignando un valor al inicio:

```
var line1 = System.Console.ReadLine().Trim();
char salida = ' ';  //Inicializado con 1 espacio
```

---

<sub>*Dicho esto, entiendo que no tiene lógica estar imprimiendo el último caracter dos veces, pero eso ya depende de la lógica de tu programa.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Como te comentan Mariano y Miquel el problema es que se podría llegar a esa instrucción con la variable salida sin asignar (concretamente si el usuario introduce una cadena vacía o únicamente espacios).

En cualquier caso otra opción para realizar la conversión sería utilizar LINQ:

```
        var line1 = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
        var salida = line1
            .Select(c => char.IsLower(c) ? char.ToUpper(c) : char.ToLower(c));

        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(salida));
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Te permiten usar LinQ en tu ejercicio?

```
Console.WriteLine
(
    string.Concat
    (
        input.ToList().ConvertAll(c => Char.IsLower(c) ? Char.ToUpper(c) : Char.ToLower(c))
    )
);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando [aquí](http://rextester.com/WFQN25562).